# I need a codec for my dell I8200, 10.04, dvd

Tags: drivers, dvd, codecs

I'm running 10.4 on a Dell I8200, and my DVD won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening up a terminal and copy-pasting the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras libdvdread4 && sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Then try playing DVDs again after those packages install.